# cypress not supporting urls : intranet urls

Tags: cypress

If i try to launch url of my office portal (which is working manually fine) , i am getting below error from cypress

cy.visit() failed trying to load:

https://intrauat.web.bc/cgi-bin/index

The response we received from your web server was:

> 401: Unauthorized

This was considered a failure because the status code was not 2xx.

any help please ?

thnx
shobhit

Comment: Can you open the url in a incognito browser without authorization ?

Answer (score 0):

In case your url requires oauth credentials. You can use:

```
cy.visit('https://intrauat.web.bc/cgi-bin/index', {
  auth: {
    username: 'test',
    password: 'test'
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to create with proxy.

Ref [link](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/proxy-configuration.html#Set-a-proxy-on-Linux-or-macOS)